# Add delay to beutifulsoup4 python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using this script in beautifulsoup4::

```
url = ["url1", "url2," "url3", ...]
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
for item in url:
    r = requests.get(item, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

To scrape a lot of shortened links. I don't want to send too much requests to the website because on the internet I saw it could cause a Denial of Service attack (I don't know if its true, but I don't want any problems). How can I add a delay between connecting to each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) in your loop. An example for adding a random delay of 3 to 7 seconds:

```
from time import sleep
...
sleep(randint(3, 7))
```